# Sound Input Device not detected in laptop

Tags: 12.04, sound, microphone, input-devices

I have a VAIO VPCEA23EN laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. Its unable to detect sound input hardware. How can I fix the problem. Here is the screenshot of my sound input tab.[image]

Comment: this is quite common issue.. even i have messed up my head a lot in this.
probably you must not b able to do video chats ( just video streaming without audio).
try using pavucontrol to configure audio input.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Pulse Audio Manager and then I selected the appropriate hardware from Pulse Audio. It finally started recording.